# How to get GPU kernels using global texture references thread-safe (for multiple CPU threads using a single GPU)

Tags: multithreading, cuda

We are having troubles when we are running certain GPU functions (e.g. a point tracker where we use texture references on multiple places) parallel in multiple CPU-threads (all CPU threads use the same GPU).

It seems that the 'texture references', which afaik are sort of 'global device variables' are the problem, as these are the only 'global' variables we have (note 'constant memory' might be probably also a issue but we will focus for now on the texture references problem). We use mainly texture references to 2D images (pitched-linear memory) as we are in image processing field.

How can we rewrite the kernels, which use the texture references, so that they are CPU-thread-safe ? Is it possible at all ? Note that in our framework we plan to have exactly 4 CPU threads for each GPU (each CPU-thread is a GPU-Worker-Thread which gets some 'GPU job' issued which he then executed).

This question seems to be related to the problem of 'arrays of texture references', I don't know if an array of texture reference is possible now with newer Cuda Toolkit / newer GPU architectures.
 See forum postings at

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/376700/?comment=2688621

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/368336/cuda-programming-and-performance/-help-compilation-problem-with-cuda-texture-cuda-texture-usage/

Or just search the nvidia cuda forum for 'texture references array' and notice that seems to be really an hot topic :-)

In one of this postings a function 'cuTexRefCreate' was mentioned, is that the way to go ? I suppose it can be used also in the cuda runtime api. But it seems to be deprecated, so that may not be a safe way.

Any help on this question would be appreciated. Note any possible strategies should work also on Fermi architecture GPUs.

An related question is also whether this multi-threading issue is also a problem for latest Kepler architecture where pointers which are of type 'const __restrict' may get mapped automatically to a texture object.

Comment: You haven't actually described the problem you are having- What are "troubles"?

Comment: Actually, different things can happen: E.g. our point-tracker can crash, or it gives incorrect results. A dense GPU optical flow algorithm we use gives incorrect results (incorrect 'motion fields'). Both algorithms work perfectly when only one CPU-thread manages the GPU.

Comment: by the way, our current GPU-job framework (using a 'GPUWorker' class) is described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491581/good-strategy-multi-gpu-handling-with-cpu-threads-cuda-context-creation-overhea

Comment: Voting to close.  SO expects you to provide an SSCCE.org type code to demonstrate your problem.  It's possible, it simply requires effort.

Answer (score 5):

Textures need to be global objects, hence thread-safety is a concern the same way as it is with any global variable shared by multiple threads. The possible solutions are also similar, you can use the typical concurrency constructs to ensure thread-safety as you would use otherwise,
e.g. a mutex to ensure that only one thread binds the texture and the others use the ref created by this.

What I'm not entirely sure of is whether the texture reference manipulation functions themselves are thread-safe, i.e. whether you need to make sure that texture manipulations do not happen concurrently on the same reference.

However, what you should really consider is [texture objects](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__TEXTURE__OBJECT.html#group__CUDART__TEXTURE__OBJECT) which although are supported only on CC >=3.0, they are [not required to be globally declared](https://developer.nvidia.com/content/cuda-pro-tip-kepler-texture-objects-improve-performance-and-flexibility).

**EDIT:**
NVIDIA engineers confirmed that thread reference manipulation functions are thread-safe.

Comment: Hey ,  how would you solve the same problem with Constant memory